# Replacing quotation marks with \quotation and \quote

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a document containing many quotation marks. I need to replace all pairs of `"` with `\quotation{` (beginning) and `}` (ending), for use in ConTeXt, e.g.:

```
"Do not be afraid," said the tiger, "I am a vegetarian."
```

This should become:

```
\quotation{Do not be afraid,} said the tiger, \quotation{I am a vegetarian.}
```

- There are no nested quotes in the document.
- The replacement should only appear when the quotation marks are found in pairs. If a line has an odd number of quotation marks, then changes should not made made to that line, as that is an indication that there is an error.
- If the character "/" appears between the start and ending quote, then the changes should mode be made to that line, as that is another indication of an error.
- Each paragraph appears on a single line, so the code should process the document one line at a time.

How can I replace these quotation marks with the format used by ConTeXt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not perfect, but you can try something like this -

```
sed 's/"\(.[^"]*\)"/\\quotation{\1}/g' file
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
"Do not be afraid," said the tiger, "I am a vegetarian."

[jaypal:~/Temp] sed 's/"\(.[^"]*\)"/\\quotation{\1}/g' file
\quotation{Do not be afraid,} said the tiger, \quotation{I am a vegetarian.}
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a horrible thing to automate; the complexity can be impressive:

```
She said, "Don't say 'stupid', or I'll smack you.", to John's girlfriend.
```

There's no good way to tell the difference between an embedded quote, contractions, possessive quotes, and the nesting could be horrible to match. A forgotten closing quote somewhere could completely screw up the output. (I've seen *dozens* of missing quotes in e.g. Terry Pratchett books. Is your content in better shape?)

Comment: You are right. I found, there are many contractions and single quotes such as what you show. I will change my question to only deal with double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my `awk` code, which is maybe not very elegant, but it does the job.

```
{
    # split current line into several pieces using quotation char
    split($0, a, "\"")
    # and if the number of pieces is even, which implies that the number of quotation marks is odd
    if (length(a) % 2 == 0) {
        # Then error, unclosed quotation mark
        # Handle it in some other way if you want
        print
    } else {
        # the only pieces that need to be quoted are those on even positions in array
        # so we just surround them with the desired text
        for (i = 2; i <= length(a); ++i) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                printf "%s", "\\quote{" a[i]
            } else {
                printf "%s", "}" a[i]
            }
        }
        # We should output end-of-line character manually to end the line
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

It works by splitting the line into parts using quotation characte and stores them in `a` array, so for example line, "Do not be afraid," said the tiger, "I am a vegetarian.":

```
a[1]: 
a[2]: Do not be afraid,
a[3]:  said the tiger, 
a[4]: I am a vegetarian.
a[5]:
```

a[1] and a[5] are both empty

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
perl -n -e '$a=$_;$a=~s/\"([^\"^\\]*)\"/\\quotation\{$1\}/g;print $a' < input
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e 'a "b" c "d" e\na "b" c "d e\na "b" c "d/d" e' |
sed 'h;s/"\([^"/]*\)"/\\quotation{\1}/g;/"/{g;s/^/ERROR: /}'
a \quotation{b} c \quotation{d} e
ERROR: a "b" c "d e
ERROR: a "b" c "d/d" e
```

if you don't want the `ERROR` message, then:

```
echo -e 'a "b" c "d" e\na "b" c "d e\na "b" c "d/d" e' | 
sed 'h;s/"\([^"/]*\)"/\\quotation{\1}/g;/"/g'
a \quotation{b} c \quotation{d} e
a "b" c "d e
a "b" c "d/d" e
```